# Prove $(1-\frac{8}{\pi^2})x^2\cot^2(x)+\frac{8}{\pi^2}x\cot(x)+\frac{4}{\pi^2}x^2-1\ge0$ for $x\in[0,\pi/2]$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inequality

> How to prove the following inequality:
> $$\left(1-\frac{8}{\pi^2}\right)x^2\cot^2(x)+\frac{8}{\pi^2}x\cot(x)+\frac{4}{\pi^2}x^2-1\ge0,\quad x\in[0,\pi/2]?$$

I evaluated the LHS of the above inequality numerically. I found that equality holds at $x=0$ and $x=\pi/2$, and strict inequality holds elsewhere. The LHS is not a monotonic function; as $x$ increases it first increases and then decreases. I derived the derivative of the LHS and the results are quite messy. Is there any easier ways of proving the inequality?

Comment: I know you said the derivative was messy; can you at least find the critical points and show they correspond to positive values?

Comment: About the sub-interval $[0,1]$, that is a consequence of the fact that for moderately large values of $n$ we have $\zeta(2n)\approx 1$.

Answer (score 4):

A partial answer - I am going to show that the given inequality holds for every $x\in(0,1]$.

Since the cotangent is the logarithmic derivative of the sine function we have
$$ \cot x = \frac{1}{x} + \sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac{1}{x-n\pi}+\frac{1}{x+n\pi}\right) \tag{1} $$
and
$$ \frac{1-\pi z\cot(\pi z)}{2} = \sum_{n\geq 1}\zeta(2n) z^{2n}.\tag{2} $$
This gives the Taylor series of $z^2\cot(z)^2$ too, and allow us to state that the given LHS is
$$ \left(-\frac{2}{3}+\frac{20}{3 \pi ^2}\right) x^2+\left(\frac{1}{15}-\frac{32}{45 \pi ^2}\right) x^4+\sum_{k\geq 3}c_k x^{2k},\qquad c_k\geq 0\tag{3} $$
for any $x\in\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$, so the given inequality holds over the interval $\left(0,1\right]$ for sure.
That should be most of the job.

---

The given inequality is indeed equivalent to
$$\forall x\in\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right),\quad x\cot(x)\geq \frac{-4+\sqrt{\left(\pi ^2-4\right)^2-4 \left(\pi ^2-8\right) x^2}}{\pi ^2-8} $$
where the RHS is a remarkably good approximation of the LHS.
The [(generalized) Shafer-Fink inequality](https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.0753) should completely settle the question, but I have to perform some numerical experiments. In a Shafer-Fink-suitable form, the previous line can be written as
$$ \forall x>0,\quad \frac{\arctan x}{x}\geq \frac{-4+\sqrt{\left(\pi^2-4\right)^2+4 \pi ^2 x^2}}{\pi^2-8+4 x^2}\tag{4} $$

Comment: Yes, the LHS and RHS are very close. Initially, without carefully checking the numerical results, I thought these two terms are identical. Later, I found that they are indeed different, although the difference is very small.

Comment: Hi Jack, I checked the inequality provided by Theorem 1 of your paper. It seems that the inequality we want to prove is stronger, and does not follow from your results.

Comment: @junjiema2: indeed the Theorem you are mentioning is just the original Shafer-Fink inequality, and I agree it is not enough to prove $(4)$. But I showed it is possible to prove arbitrary strengthening of the original Shafer-Fink inequality, and my Theorem $4$  actually proves the last inequality over a sub-interval of $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Answer (score 3):

**Proof**:

**Fact 1**: $x\cot x \ge 1 - \frac13 x^2 - \frac{1}{38}x^4 > 0$ for all $x\in (0, 3\pi/8]$.
(The proof is given at the end. *Note*: The RHS comes from the Taylor approximation of $x\cot x$ around $x=0$, that is, $x \cot x \sim 1 - \frac13 x^2 - \frac{1}{45}x^4$, but
we need to adjust the coefficient of $x^4$ (e.g., $\frac{1}{45} \to \frac{1}{38}$) to make the inequality true on $(0, 3\pi/8]$.)

**Fact 2**: $x\cot x
\ge x(\pi/2 - x) + \frac13 x (\pi/2 - x)^3 \ge 0$ for all $x\in [3\pi/8, \pi/2]$.
(The proof is given at the end. *Note*: The RHS comes from (multiplying $x$) the Taylor approximation of $\cot x$ arround $x=\pi/2$, that is, $\cot x \sim (\pi/2 - x) + \frac13 (\pi/2 - x)^3$.)

$\phantom{2}$

We split into two cases:

**Case 1**: $0 < x \le 3\pi/8$

Using Fact 1, we have
\begin{align*}
 &\mathrm{LHS} \\
 \ge\,& \left(1-\frac{8}{\pi^2}\right) \cdot \left(1 - \frac13 x^2 - \frac{1}{38}x^4\right)^2+\frac{8}{\pi^2}\left(1 - \frac13 x^2 - \frac{1}{38}x^4\right)+\frac{4}{\pi^2}x^2-1\\
 =\,& {\frac { ( 9\,{\pi }^{2}-72 ) {x}^{8}+
   ( 228\,{\pi }^{2}-1824 ) {x}^{6}+ ( 760\,{\pi }^{2}-
   8816 ) {x}^{4}+ ( 86640-8664\,{\pi }^{2} ) {x}^{2}}{12996
   {\pi }^{2}}}
 \\
 \ge\,& 0.
\end{align*}

**Case 2**: $3\pi/8 \le x \le \pi/2$

Using Fact 2, we have
\begin{align*}
 \mathrm{LHS} &\ge \left(1-\frac{8}{\pi^2}\right)\left( x(\pi/2 - x) + \frac13 x (\pi/2 - x)^3\right)^2\\[8pt]
 &\qquad +\frac{8}{\pi^2}\left( x(\pi/2 - x) + \frac13 x (\pi/2 - x)^3\right)+\frac{4}{\pi^2}x^2-1\\[8pt]
 &= \frac{(\pi - 2x)^2}{576\pi^2}\cdot g(x)\\[8pt]
 &\ge 0
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
 g(x) &=  \left( 16\,{\pi }^{2}-128 \right) {x}^{6}+ \left( -32\,{\pi }^{3}+256
 \,\pi  \right) {x}^{5}+ \left( 24\,{\pi }^{4}-96\,{\pi }^{2}-768
 \right) {x}^{4} \\
 &\qquad + \left( -8\,{\pi }^{5}-32\,{\pi }^{3}+768\,\pi 
 \right) {x}^{3}+ \left( {\pi }^{6}+16\,{\pi }^{4}-48\,{\pi }^{2} -1536
 \right) {x}^{2}\\
 &\qquad +192\,\pi \,x-576.
\end{align*}

We are done.

---

*Proof of Fact 1*:

Using $\cos x \ge 1 - \frac12x^2 + \frac{1}{24}x^4 - \frac{1}{720}x^6$
for all $x\ge 0$ and $\sin x \le x - \frac16 x^3 + \frac{1}{120}x^5$ for all $x\ge 0$, we have, for all $x\in (0, \pi/2]$,
$$x\cot x \ge x \cdot \frac{1 - \frac12x^2 + \frac{1}{24}x^4 - \frac{1}{720}x^6}{x - \frac16 x^3 + \frac{1}{120}x^5}.$$

It suffices to prove that, for all $x\in (0, 3\pi/8]$,
$$x \cdot \frac{1 - \frac12x^2 + \frac{1}{24}x^4 - \frac{1}{720}x^6}{x - \frac16 x^3 + \frac{1}{120}x^5}
\ge 1 - \frac13x^2 - \frac{1}{38}x^4$$
or
$$3x^4 - 41x^2 + 56 \ge 0$$
which is true.

We are done.

---

*Proof of Fact 2*:

Using $\cos x \ge (\pi/2 - x) - \frac16(\pi/2 - x)^3$ for all $x \in [0, \pi/2]$ and $\sin x \le 1 - \frac12(\pi/2 - x)^2 + \frac{1}{24}(\pi/2 - x)^4$ for all $x \in [0, \pi/2]$, we have, for all $x\in (0, \pi/2]$,
$$x\cot x \ge x \cdot \frac{(\pi/2 - x) - \frac16(\pi/2 - x)^3}{1 - \frac12(\pi/2 - x)^2 + \frac{1}{24}(\pi/2 - x)^4}.$$

It suffices to prove that, for all $x\in [3\pi/8, \pi/2]$,
$$x \cdot \frac{(\pi/2 - x) - \frac16(\pi/2 - x)^3}{1 - \frac12(\pi/2 - x)^2 + \frac{1}{24}(\pi/2 - x)^4}
\ge x(\pi/2 - x) + \frac13 x (\pi/2 - x)^3$$
or
$$x(\pi - 2x + 6)(2x + 6 - \pi)(\pi - 2x)^5 \ge 0$$
which is true.

We are done.

Comment: And how are these facts derived? A simple Taylor series inspection, or something more complex?

Comment: @FShrike Thanks for comment. I give a detailed proof now.

Comment: Nice, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Jack's inequality (4), I'd like to post some numerical results[image]

The LHS is given by the red curve, and the RHS of (4) in Jack's answer shown by the black dashed curve. We see that these two curves are almost indistinguishable! The (generalized) Shafer-Fink inequality in Jack's paper (Theorem 1, I haven't checked other inequalities) would give us the blue curve, which is looser than the RHS.

This is actually a very cool inequality. A proof would be quite interesting.